# why tensorflow just outputs killed

Tags: tensorflow

When I run my tensorflow app, it just outputs "killed". How do I debug this?

[source code](https://github.com/reachlin/machinelearning/blob/master/tensorflow/sample_cnn.py)

```
root@8e4a3a65184e:~/tensorflow# python sample_cnn.py 
INFO:tensorflow:Using default config.
INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_session_config': None, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_tf_random_seed': 1, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_model_dir': 'data/convnet_model', '_save_summary_steps': 100}
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
2017-08-17 12:56:53.160481: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-17 12:56:53.160536: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-17 12:56:53.160545: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-17 12:56:53.160550: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-08-17 12:56:53.160555: W tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
Killed
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When I run your code I get the same behavior, after typing `dmesg` you'll see a trace like, which confirms what gdelab was hinting at:

```
[38607.234089] python3 invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x24280ca(GFP_HIGHUSER_MOVABLE|__GFP_ZERO), nodemask=0, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
[38607.234090] python3 cpuset=/ mems_allowed=0
[38607.234094] CPU: 3 PID: 1420 Comm: python3 Tainted: G           O    4.9.0-3-amd64 #1 Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u2
[38607.234094] Hardware name: Dell Inc. XPS 15 9560/05FFDN, BIOS 1.2.4 03/29/2017
[38607.234096]  0000000000000000 ffffffffa9f28414 ffffa50090317cf8 ffff940effa5f040
[38607.234097]  ffffffffa9dfe050 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0101ffffa9d82dd0
[38607.234098]  e09c7db7f06d0ac2 00000000ffffffff 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
[38607.234100] Call Trace:
[38607.234104]  [<ffffffffa9f28414>] ? dump_stack+0x5c/0x78
[38607.234106]  [<ffffffffa9dfe050>] ? dump_header+0x78/0x1fd
[38607.234108]  [<ffffffffa9d8047a>] ? oom_kill_process+0x21a/0x3e0
[38607.234109]  [<ffffffffa9d800fd>] ? oom_badness+0xed/0x170
[38607.234110]  [<ffffffffa9d80911>] ? out_of_memory+0x111/0x470
[38607.234111]  [<ffffffffa9d85b4f>] ? __alloc_pages_slowpath+0xb7f/0xbc0
[38607.234112]  [<ffffffffa9d85d8e>] ? __alloc_pages_nodemask+0x1fe/0x260
[38607.234113]  [<ffffffffa9dd7c3e>] ? alloc_pages_vma+0xae/0x260
[38607.234115]  [<ffffffffa9db39ba>] ? handle_mm_fault+0x111a/0x1350
[38607.234117]  [<ffffffffa9c5fd84>] ? __do_page_fault+0x2a4/0x510
[38607.234118]  [<ffffffffaa207658>] ? page_fault+0x28/0x30
...
[38607.234158] [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
...
[38607.234332] [ 1396]  1000  1396  4810969  3464995    6959      21        0             0 python3
[38607.234332] Out of memory: Kill process 1396 (python3) score 568 or sacrifice child
[38607.234357] Killed process 1396 (python3) total-vm:19243876kB, anon-rss:13859980kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
[38607.720757] oom_reaper: reaped process 1396 (python3), now anon-rss:0kB, file-rss:0kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

Which basically means python was starting too consume too much memory and the kernel decided to kill the process. If you add some prints in your code you'll see that `mnist_classifier.train()` is the function which is active. However some dumb tests (as removing the logging and lowering the steps, did not seem to help here).

Comment: Thanks for your good explantation @amo-ej1

Answer (score 11):

As the other commenters said, your OS kills your process because it runs out of memory. You are trying to build a huge network. Lets look at your last dense layer. It has 65536 inputs and 65536 units. Each unit has weight for each input, so that makes 65536 * 65536 = 4294967296 weights. Weights are based on your input dtype, and I think yours is float64, so lets multiply that by 64 and you get 32GB of weights (65536 * 65536 * 64 / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 / 8 = 32). And all these weights are a single tensor that has to be operated on as a whole, so it has to fit into RAM entirely. Does your system have 32GB of RAM?

Answer (score 5):

Your program is killed by your OS, Tensorflow has no clue why, that's why it does not output anything. It's probably due to an out of memory error.

Check if your `syslog` contains a line like this:

```
<date> <computer> kernel: [...] Out of memory: Kill process <id> (python) score <...> or sacrifice child
```

If so, you need to increase the memory allowed for python, and/or decrease the memory used by your program.