# Tensorflow crash in mnist-deep.py

Tags: keras, tensorflow

currently running the training using mnist-deep.py from Tensorflow tutorial on Geforce 1080 (8Gb) with on top 16GB of ram on the machine. All latest CUDA libraries and drivers are installed. Everything is running on Tensorflow 1.3. The mnist-deep.py script has been working fine  without any errors until I decided to perform the training of some Keras vdsr training (https://github.com/jackie840129/VDSR-reduction_with-Keras). Training hanged and GPU was lost (no access through nvidia-smi). After rebooting was trying to perform back the mnist-deep.py and getting the errors below constantly. I am still unclear what could causing the problem. Reboot, reinstall cuda don't seem to address the issues. Reimaging the machine seems to solve the problem but this doesn't seem to be any practical way. Any ideas what could be causing the problem at the first place and how to solve it for good?

```
Successfully downloaded train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz 9912422 bytes.
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/train-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Successfully downloaded train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz 28881 bytes.
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/train-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Successfully downloaded t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz 1648877 bytes.
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/t10k-images-idx3-ubyte.gz
Successfully downloaded t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz 4542 bytes.
Extracting /tmp/tensorflow/mnist/input_data/t10k-labels-idx1-ubyte.gz
Saving graph to: /tmp/tmpgb1l75z_
2017-10-18 15:36:28.098787: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow 
library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.1 instructions, but these are 
available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-10-18 15:36:28.098807: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow 
library wasn't compiled to use SSE4.2 instructions, but these are 
available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-10-18 15:36:28.098814: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow 
library wasn't compiled to use AVX instructions, but these are 
available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-10-18 15:36:28.098820: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow 
library wasn't compiled to use AVX2 instructions, but these are 
available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-10-18 15:36:28.098825: W 
tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:45] The TensorFlow 
library wasn't compiled to use FMA instructions, but these are 
available on your machine and could speed up CPU computations.
2017-10-18 15:36:28.760202: I 
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:893] successful 
NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be 
at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero
2017-10-18 15:36:28.760643: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:955] Found device 0 
with properties: 
name: GeForce GTX 1080
major: 6 minor: 1 memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.7715
pciBusID 0000:01:00.0
Total memory: 7.92GiB
Free memory: 7.81GiB
2017-10-18 15:36:28.760657: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:976] DMA: 0 
2017-10-18 15:36:28.760664: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:986] 0:   Y 
2017-10-18 15:36:28.760672: I 
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating 
TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1080, pci 
bus id: 0000:01:00.0)
2017-10-18 15:36:31.546892: E 
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1073] failed to get 
elapsed time between events: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_READY
2017-10-18 15:36:32.547035: E 
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:1073] failed to get 
elapsed time between events: CUDA_ERROR_NOT_READY
2017-10-18 15:36:32.549299: E 
tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:366] failed to create 
cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2017-10-18 15:36:32.549317: W 
tensorflow/stream_executor/stream.cc:1756] attempting to perform BLAS 
operation using StreamExecutor without BLAS support
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/nmh/env/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1327, in _do_call
return fn(*args)
File "/home/nmh/env/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1306, in _run_fn
status, run_metadata)
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 88, in __exit__
next(self.gen)
File "/home/nmh/env/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 466, in 
raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Blas GEMM 
launch failed : a.shape=(50, 3136), b.shape=(3136, 1024), m=50, 
n=1024, k=3136
 [[Node: fc1/MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, 
transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]
(fc1/Reshape, fc1/Variable/read)]]
 [[Node: Mean_1/_7 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, 
recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", 
send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", 
send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_79_Mean_1", 
tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]
()]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "mnist_deep.py", line 178, in <module>
tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
File "/home/nmh/env/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
_sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
File "mnist_deep.py", line 165, in main
x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
File "/home/nmh/env/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 541, in eval
return _eval_using_default_session(self, feed_dict, self.graph, 
session)
File "/home/nmh/env/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 4085, in 
_eval_using_default_session
return session.run(tensors, feed_dict)
File "/home/nmh/env/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 895, in run
run_metadata_ptr)
File "/home/nmh/env/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1124, in _run
feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
File "/home/nmh/env/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1321, in _do_run
options, run_metadata)
File "/home/nmh/env/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1340, in _do_call
raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: Blas GEMM 
launch failed : a.shape=(50, 3136), b.shape=(3136, 1024), m=50, 
n=1024, k=3136
 [[Node: fc1/MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, 
transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]
(fc1/Reshape, fc1/Variable/read)]]
 [[Node: Mean_1/_7 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, 
recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", 
send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", 
send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_79_Mean_1", 
tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]
()]]

Caused by op 'fc1/MatMul', defined at:
File "mnist_deep.py", line 178, in <module>
tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
File "/home/nmh/env/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 48, in run
_sys.exit(main(_sys.argv[:1] + flags_passthrough))
File "mnist_deep.py", line 134, in main
y_conv, keep_prob = deepnn(x)
File "mnist_deep.py", line 83, in deepnn
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)
File "/home/nmh/env/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 1844, in matmul
a, b, transpose_a=transpose_a, transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
File "/home/nmh/env/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_math_ops.py", line 1289, in 
_mat_mul
transpose_b=transpose_b, name=name)
 File "/home/nmh/env/lib/python3.6/site  
/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
op_def=op_def)
File "/home/nmh/env/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2630, in create_op
original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
File "/home/nmh/env/lib/python3.6/site-
packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1204, in __init__
self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: 
disable=protected-access

InternalError (see above for traceback): Blas GEMM launch failed : 
a.shape=(50, 3136), b.shape=(3136, 1024), m=50, n=1024, k=3136
 [[Node: fc1/MatMul = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=false, 
transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]
(fc1/Reshape, fc1/Variable/read)]]
 [[Node: Mean_1/_7 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, 
recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", 
send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", 
send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_79_Mean_1", 
tensor_type=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]
()]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error once. It was caused by an Out Of Memory error (the OS killed my training because of the RAM it took), since that's pretty violent I also lost contact with the GPU. Some rebootings and removing the GPU - setting it back in worked.

You can look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45735858/why-tensorflow-just-outputs-killed/45736139#45736139) to know if your problem is the same. If so, you'll probably have to use a smaller network.