# Does Swap memory help if my RAM is insufficient?

Tags: tensorflow, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi3

New to StackOverflow and don't have enough credits to post a comment. So opening a new question.

I am running into the same issue as this:

[why tensorflow just outputs killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45735858/why-tensorflow-just-outputs-killed)

In this scenario, does SWAP memory help?

**Little more info on the platform:**

- Ras Pi 3 on Ubuntu Mate 16.04
- RAM - 1 GB
- Storage - 32 GB SD card
- Framework: Tensorflow
- Network architecture- similar to complexity of AlexNet.

Appreciate any help!

Thanks
SK

Answer (score 0):

While swap may stave off the hard failure as seen in the linked question, swapping will generally doom your inference. The difference in throughput and latency b/w RAM and any other form of storage is simply far too large.

As a rough estimate, RAM throughput is about 100x that of even high quality SD cards. The factor for I/O operations per second is even larger, at somewhere between 100,000 and 5,000,000.